# I have made a DAO handler by using mapping of daoName and bytes32 and generated a random no. using keccak but the output is still coming 0;

Tags: solidity, remix, mapping, keccak, dao

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract DAOManager {
  mapping(bytes32 => string) public daos;

  function _registerDAO(string memory daoName) public returns(bytes32){
    bytes32 daoUuid = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(daoName, block.number, msg.sender));
    daos[daoUuid] = daoName;
    return daoUuid;
  }
}
```

Comment: What "output" are you talking about? Please add more context and include the code for what you are fetching from the contract.

Comment: How are you calling `_registerDAO`?